# php in_array not finding number

Tags: php

in_array isnt finding a number inside my array

print_r of `$supparr`:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

Code:

```
if(in_array($r->prodid, $supparr)){ echo 'yes' ; }else{ echo 'no';  }
```

I have echo'd $r->prodid and it is definetly showing the number 1. The number 1 is in the array so I can't figure out why in_array isn't picking it up? 
It always returns no results. I have tried hardcoding 1 below and putting it in speechmarks and still get no results:

```
if(in_array(1, $supparr)){ echo 'yes' ; }else{ echo 'no';  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do a `var_dump()` instead for both. it'll show type AND length of string. if there's something goofy in there, like unprintable characters, hidden html, etc..it could be throwing off the match.

Comment: never mind I have resolved it!

Comment: wow, thanks for the negs and getting me banned guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_search() or You have several ways of solving the problem. One is to just enter true. Setting the third parameter true checks the type of the values supplied and being checked.

```
if(in_array($r->prodid, $supparr, true)){ 
    echo 'yes' ; 
}else{ 
    echo 'no'; 
}
```

The second way is to type cast or just make the number a string.

```
if(in_array("$r->prodid", $supparr)){ 
    echo 'yes' ; 
}else{ 
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: It would help if you explained 1) What is wrong with the method the OP is using. 2) Why these are 'better'. Given that the code supplied works as demonstrated.

Comment: Did it work in both cases?

Comment: If you modify the supplied' 'codepad' example to use strings then it still works fine. PHP does 'automatic type conversion' as required.

Comment: Have you tried setting the third parameter to true. Because setting it to true will force it to check the type otherwise the values in the array are strings

Comment: Thanks all, all sorted - it was a typo in my code.!